# How to align an element by it's parent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to do a method for elements in order to align the element to the parent container, when is possible (absolute positioning required in this simple version). Here is the testing page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Align Element</title>
         <style>

        .jGp_jan {
            position:fixed;
            background-color:#DDD;
            border:2px solid #000;
            padding:-1px;
            width:320px;
            height:auto;
            border-radius:6px;
            box-shadow:8px 8px 12px black;
        }

        </style>
        <script>

        Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "align", {
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false,
            value: function(args) { 
                var pw = this.parentNode.clientWidth;
                var ph = this.parentNode.clientHeight;
                var w = this.offsetWidth;
                var h = this.offsetHeight;
                if(args.indexOf("h")>=0) this.style.left = String(Math.round((pw/2)-(w/2)))+"px";
                if(args.indexOf("v")>=0) this.style.top = String(Math.round((ph/2)-(h/2)))+"px";
            }
        });
        function ini(){
            document.getElementById("test").align("hv");
        }

        </script>
     </head>

    <body onload="ini();">
        <div class="jGp_jan" id="jGp_jan_img" style="top:8px; left:8px; width:640px; height:460px;">
            <div id="{cabecalho}" style="display:inline; background-color:#666; border-radius:6px; height:22px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;">
                <button id="{btnFechar}" style="float:left;"> X </button>
                <div id="{titulo}" style="float:left; font-weight:bold; color:#FFC;"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:22px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;">
                <div id="{conteudo}" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFF; border-radius:6px;">
                    <div id="test" style="display:block; position:absolute;"><br />This is a test<br /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error is a little enigmatic:

```
TypeError: '' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementById("test").align("hv")')
```

I think there is some detail I'm missing... can you see?

Comment: Do you mean to use `document.getElementById('test').style="css-property:value";` ?

Comment: If you want to use with absolute positioning, text-align don't work anymore and you have to pinpoint it yourself.

Comment: I mean to change specific css properties "left" and "top" to put the div at the center. The text is only to fill the div (to see if is actually centered), could be an image, or whatever.

Comment: Where is the guys that wish to close or down vote my question? The reasons to exclude this question from the forum?